# How can I do a cast to solve an explicit conversion needed error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I’m trying to access my list in the view like this:

```
  List<xxxx.Models.Enrollment> newStudentEnrollment=ViewBag.studentrecord;
```

But I get an error message that says: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)…
I’ve tried using FirstOrDefault() and ToList() like I’ve seen worked for others in this forum but neither worked for me.  Also tried removing the ToList() from here 'ViewBag.studentrecord = newRecord.ToList();' in the controller

Here’s what I’m doing in my controller….

```
   var StudentRecord = (from E in db.Enrollments
                             join S in db.Students.Where(r => r.StudentID == intStudentNumber)
                    on E.StudentID equals S.StudentID into JoinedStudent
                             from AllStudent in JoinedStudent.DefaultIfEmpty()

                             select new
                             {

                               CourseID=E.CourseID,
                               StudentID=E.StudentID,
                               Date=E.Date,
                               InstructorFullName=E.InstructorFullName,
                               classDays=E.classDays,
                               listOfDays=E.listOfDays,
                               listOfTeachers=E.listOfTeachers,
                                 IsStudentEnroll = AllStudent != null ? true : false
                             }).ToList();


        var newRecord = from r in StudentRecord where r.StudentID==67 select r;
        ViewBag.studentrecord = newRecord.ToList();
```

Seeing that my data is of type List I thought I could do this…

```
 List<xxxx.Models.Enrollment> newStudentEnrollment=ViewBag.studentrecord;
```

How do I do a cast with this or make it work in any way?

Thanks very much for any help.

EDIT:

So I tried this:

```
  List<xxxx.Models.Enrollment> newStudentEnrollment =  (List<xxxx.Models.Enrollment>)ViewBag.studentrecord;
```

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType9`7[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Boolean]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[xxxx.Models.Enrollment]'.

Also tried:

```
    List<xxxx.Models.Enrollment> newStudentEnrollment = ViewBag.studentrecord as List<xxxx.Models.Enrollment>;
```

but newStudentEnrollment was null.  I think it has to do with the join clause.  It combined two objects so I somehow have to create a generic object of type list.  Only I don't know how...any ideas?  Thanks.

UPDATE

I changed the type from a Join to Enrollment like this.
var newEnrollment = from e in context.Enrollment where e.SomeId ==someNumber select e;

Than in the view this worked:
  List newStudentEnrollment =  (List)ViewBag.studentrecord;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast your `ViewBag.studentrecord` to `List<xxxx.Models.Enrollment>`

```
 List<xxxx.Models.Enrollment> newStudentEnrollment = (List<xxxx.Models.Enrollment>)ViewBag.studentrecord;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
List<xxxx.Models.Enrollment> newStudentEnrollment=ViewBag.studentrecord as List<xxxx.Models.Enrollment>;
```